# gRegex not parsing " characters

Tags: c, regex, glib

I need to be able to extract Mime Content-Type headers from SMTP messages. For this purpose I am using the `g_regex` part of the `glib` library and I have created [this regular expression](http://regexr.com/3as4j).

Note: In `g_regex` I changed `[\s]` subpatterns to `(\r\n)` as the latter - with model Content-Type headers more precisely - are apparently not recognized by regexr. The resultant regex is

```
((\r\n){2}((([--]{2,}[=][a-zA-Z0-9._]+)(\r\n))((((Content([\x2D][a-zA-Z]+)+)[:]([\x09\x0C\x20]*([a-zA-Z0-9\x2D]+([\x2F][a-zA-Z\x2D]+)?)[;]?)(\r\n))([\x09\x0C\x20]*[a-zA-Z]+[\x09\x0C\x20]*[=][\x22]?[a-zA-Z\x2D\x2E]+[\x22]?)?)(\r\n))+)(\r\n))
```

Please find my C code below:

```
GRegex *regex;
GMatchInfo *match_infoX;
gint start_content_pos, end_content_pos;

regex = g_regex_new("((\r\n){2}((([--]{2,}[=][a-zA-Z0-9._]+)(\r\n))((((Content([\x2D][a-zA-Z]+)+)[:]([\x09\x0C\x20]*([a-zA-Z0-9\x2D]+([\x2F][a-zA-Z\x2D]+)?)[;]?)(\r\n))([\x09\x0C\x20]*[a-zA-Z]+[\x09\x0C\x20]*[=][\x22]?[a-zA-Z\x2D\x2E]+[\x22]?)?)(\r\n))+)(\r\n))", 0, 0, NULL);
g_regex_match(regex, SMTP_Message_string, 0, &match_info);
while (g_match_info_matches(match_info))
{
    start_content_pos = end_content_pos = -1;

    gchar *word = g_match_info_fetch(match_info, 0);
    g_match_info_fetch_pos(match_infoX, 0, &start_content_pos, &end_content_pos);

    g_print("Found: %s\n", word);
    g_free(word);
    g_match_info_next(match_info, NULL);
}
g_match_info_free(match_info);
g_regex_unref(regex);
```

I have the following issue:

For some strange reason the regular expression is working on regexr - link above - but is failing miserably with no apparent reason when used with `g_regex`. Specifically, in `g_regex` the subexpression

```
((\r\n){2}((([--]{2,}[=][a-zA-Z0-9._]+)(\r\n)) ((((Content([\x2D][a-zA-Z]+)+)[:]([\x09\x0C\x20]*([a-zA-Z0-9\x2D]+([\x2F][a-zA-Z\x2D]+)?)[;]?)(\r\n))([\x09\x0C\x20]*[a-zA-Z]+[\x09\x0C\x20]*[=])))))
```

is working fine, but

```
((\r\n){2}((([--]{2,}[=][a-zA-Z0-9._]+)(\r\n)) ((((Content([\x2D][a-zA-Z]+)+)[:]([\x09\x0C\x20]*([a-zA-Z0-9\x2D]+([\x2F][a-zA-Z\x2D]+)?)[;]?)(\r\n))([\x09\x0C\x20]*[a-zA-Z]+[\x09\x0C\x20]*[=][\x22]?)))))
```

is not, which means the problem is in the `[\x22]` - the `"` character. I am unable to understand what is wrong. I have checked with a Hex veiwer, and the hex code is indeed `22`.

Where is the problem? Might it be a glib bug or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?  I listened to a Gerald Celente interview on (King World News)[www.kingworldnews.com] last night ^ ^

Comment: why not use a library like `GMime` and if you do want to retrieve MIME Content-type headers only why not a regex like this: `\s+--[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s+Content-Type:(.*)[\r\n]+`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do not get any error. Simply g_match_info_matches(match_info) evaluates to false and tthe while loop is never executed. Glad you like Gerald Celente :)

Comment: @Anirudha I am boud to use glib. It is a project requirement. Whell your suggested expression should work. However I need the regex to be 1. as flexible as possible in order to also match header not 100% conformant to the relevant RFC; 2. match as many headers as possible in one shot for the purpose of avoing false positive, such as chunck of message quoting some Mime Content-type headers... I cannot avoid this 100%, but I need to make it as hard as possible to happen.

Comment: To contributor suggestint to escape [\x22], I will try, bear with me. The project takes some 20 minutes to compile. I don't know why by your comment strangely disappeared. Sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humor me and try this code:

```
regex = g_regex_new("((\r\n){2}((([--]{2,}[=][a-zA-Z0-9._]+)(\r\n)) ((((Content([\x2D][a-zA-Z]+)+)[:]([\x09\x0C\x20]*([a-zA-Z0-9\x2D]+([\x2F][a-zA-Z\x2D]+)?)[;]?)(\r\n))([\x09\x0C\x20]*[a-zA-Z]+[\x09\x0C\x20]*[=][\x22\x22]?)))))", 0, 0, NULL);
g_regex_match(regex, SMTP_Message_string, 0, &match_info);
```

If you look closely, I changed the end of your regex to `[\x22\x22]`.  My hunch is that the double quote is somehow reserved and it sees an open expression and is therefore failing.

Comment: Thanks, your answer did put me on the right track. Since " is a reserved character, I used escaped it. Specifically I changed [\x22] to [\"]. Thanks.